# Search for and Add Values from One Dataframe at specific row/index to another df at specific row/index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

**Pandas Manipulation DF Question Here**

I want to create a new column in my original DF (df) that is a value at a specific index from another DF (dfKey).

I am a bit stuck (I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't decode the current error message `'KeyError: 'Name'`).

**Data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'Code': [250, 200, 875, 1200],
    'Metric1': [1.4, 350, 0.2, 500],
    'Metric999': [1.2, 375, 0.22, 505],} 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Code','Metric1', 'Metric999',])

df.set_index('Code', inplace=True) #Set Code as Row Index
print(df)

raw_dataKey = {'Code': [250, 1200, 205, 2899, 875, 5005],
    'Ticker': ['NVID', 'ATVI', 'CRM', 'GOOGL', 'TSLA','GE', ],       
    'Name': ['NVIDA Corp', 'Activision', 'SalesForce', 'Googlyness', 'Tesla Company','General Electric']} 
dfKey = pd.DataFrame(raw_dataKey , columns = ['Code','Ticker', 'Name'])
dfKey.set_index('Code', inplace=True) #Set Code as Row Index
print(dfKey)
```

**Desired Output** (`df.head()`):

```
      Ticker           Name  Code  Metric1  Metric999
Code  
250     NVID     NVIDA Corp   250      1.4       1.20
200      NaN            NaN   200    350.0     375.00
875     TSLA  Tesla Company   875      0.2       0.22
1200    ATVI     Activision  1200    500.0     505.00
```

I think the best way to do this is a for loop, as all the other methods I've tried (such as `df['Name']=np.where(df['Code']==dfKey['Code'], dfKey['Name'])`) only compare/test each row at the same index; no searching.

**My latest attempt:**

```
codes=df.index.tolist()
codes

for code in codes:
    #1. Find Name and Ticker in Key
    name = dfKey['Name'].loc[code]
    ticker = dfKey['Ticker'].loc[code]
    #2. Put Name and Ticker back in original
    df['Name'].loc[code] = name 
    df['Ticker'].loc[code] = ticker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `merge`:

```
dfKey.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Output:

```
     Ticker              Name  Metric1  Metric999
Code                                             
200     CRM        SalesForce    350.0     375.00
250    NVID        NVIDA Corp      1.4       1.20
875    TSLA     Tesla Company      0.2       0.22
1200   ATVI        Activision    500.0     505.00
2899  GOOGL        Googlyness      NaN        NaN
5005     GE  General Electric      NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Oh Duhh! I knew there had to be an easier way to do this (gotta love that python syntax). Top answer for speed (even though I suppose MaxU's form is a bit more elegant)! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [13]: df.join(dfKey)
Out[13]:
      Metric1  Metric999 Ticker           Name
Code
250       1.4       1.20   NVID     NVIDA Corp
200     350.0     375.00    NaN            NaN
875       0.2       0.22   TSLA  Tesla Company
1200    500.0     505.00   ATVI     Activision
```